# Unable to bootstrap with winrm

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

when i run

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm <my ec2 fqdn> -x Administrator -P "<password>" -r "role[myrole]"
```

my instance is inside vpc and i have attached eip In place od   i gave both my private ip and public ip

```
ERROR: Batch render command returned 
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to ["10.220.15.254"] as Administrator 
Response: Bad HTTP response returned from server (401).
```

what should be my  for windows instance.

Comment: Have you tried using `knife-ec2` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You should configure Windows Remote Management in the server as described at http://docs.opscode.com/plugin_knife_windows.html

Your error is due to Basic Authentication not being enabled, you have to run the following command in the Windows machine before attempting the bootstrap:

`winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}`

If running it from PowerShell put the parameter in single quotes `'@{Basic="true"}'`

Comment: how to execute the above script before launching the instance